# pinging websites from array in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, cmd, ping

```
import subproccess
import sys

mylist= ['google.com','bbc.com','yahoo.com','gmail.com','hotmail.com',
         'amazon.com']

for ping in mylist(0,5):
    result = os.system("ping  %s" % ping)
    result.stdout=open("test.txt","w")
    result.stdout.close()
```

Can someone please find the mistake in my code? I want to call this script from cmd terminal. The aim of this code is to ping each of the website every time and then write the result in a text file. I'm quite new with python and I don't know how to build a proper code.

Comment: Can you share the specific errors you are encountering? There are multiple problems to your code, including missing modules, missing equal signs, iterating through the list, logical operation order for the file.

Comment: You have errors everywhere in your code, where is the `=` in the list assignment, what is `mylist(1,6)` supposed to be doing or  `result.stdout=open("test.txt","w")`? You seem to be lacking some of the very basics of python so you might want to read a tutorial or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- os not imported
- mylist = ['google.com','bbc.com','yahoo.com','gmail.com','hotmail.com','amazon.com']
- for ping in mylist:
- result = os.system("ping  -c 1 %s" % ping)
- f = open("test.txt","w") (open the file before entering the loop, else it would rewrite the file everytime the loop iterates)

  ```
  import os

  mylist= ['google.com','bbc.com','yahoo.com','gmail.com','hotmail.com',
           'amazon.com']

  f = open("file.txt", 'w')
  for ping in mylist:
      result = os.system("ping -c 1 %s" % ping)
      f.write(ping + " : " +str(result) + "\n")
  f.close()
  ```

Comment: thank you very much so . I iwll leave the  result.stdout.close() in the loop ?and does this write the result in the file?

Comment: @user6367569 You should see the file handling in python again. Your file handling code is wrong above. Btw you should put close() outside the loop.
I have edited the complete code above.

Comment: I tryied it but the problem is that it doesn't recognise the f.write(ping + " : " +result + "\n")       ping

Comment: @user6367569 i just edited the code. There was a small error. You should debug some of the small errors by yourself instead of asking everytime on stackoverflow everytime.